# I need to measure Performance : AUC for this code of NLTK and skLearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk

The code below measures precision and recall and F-measure ([source](http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/17/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-precision-recall/)). How can I measure AUC?

```
import collections
import nltk.metrics
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]
print 'train on %d instances, test on %d instances' % (len(trainfeats), len(testfeats))

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)

for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testfeats):
    refsets[label].add(i)
    observed = classifier.classify(feats)
    testsets[observed].add(i)

print 'pos precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
print 'pos recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
print 'pos F-measure:', nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])
print 'neg precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
print 'neg recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
print 'neg F-measure:', nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])
```

Comment: You need to decide a scoring function for your data. Do you have it?

Comment: no I don't have it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear if you are requesting AUC of ROC or Precision-Recall curve. However, instead of storing the indices of examples in sets, you can store the labels in lists and use sklearn's `auc` function after running [`precision_recall_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html) or [`roc_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html):

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc

def label2int(label):
    if label == 'pos':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

y_true, y_score = [], []

for i, (feats, label_true) in enumerate(testfeats):
    label_predicted = classifier.classify(feats)
    y_true.append(label2int(label_true))
    y_score.append(label2int(label_predicted))

# Precision-Recall AUC
precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label=1)
pr_auc = auc(recall, precision)
print "Precision-Recall AUC: %.2f" % pr_auc
# ROC AUC
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label=1)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print "ROC AUC: %.2f" % roc_auc
```

> Precision-Recall AUC: 0.82
>
> ROC AUC: 0.73